# Indexing through Characters

Tags: indexing, rust

```
use std::io;

fn solution(inputString: String) -> bool {
    
    let mut num_bool = true;
    let mut index_tracker = 0;
    
    /*
    let mut inputString = String::new();
  
    io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut inputString)
    .expect("Not valid");

    inputString = inputString.trim().to_string();
    */

    
        
    for new_char in inputString.chars() {
        if new_char != inputString.chars().nth(inputString.chars().count() - (index_tracker + 1)) {
            num_bool = false;
            break;
        //print!("{:?} ", inputString.chars().nth(new_char));
        //print!("{:?} \n", inputString.chars().nth(inputString.chars().count() - (index_tracker + 1)));
        //print!("\nNext");
            }
            index_tracker += 1;
    }
    print!("{}", num_bool);
    return num_bool;
}
```

```
Error Log: error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs on line 21:24
   |
26 |         if new_char != inputString.chars().nth(inputString.chars().count() - (index_tracker + 1)) {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `char`, found enum `Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `char`
              found enum `Option<char>`

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Comment: You can wrap `new_char` in `Some` => `if Some(new_char ) != inputString...`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is trying to tell you that the `nth()` function returns an `Option`, which you are trying to compare to a `char`.

There are many ways to check an `Option`'s underlying value. One typical idiomatic solution is with `if let Some(c) = an_option_value {...}`.

What exactly are you trying to do in this function? This implementation looks very inefficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was a naive way to find if the given string is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerer noted, `nth` returns an `Option<char>`.

A couple possible solutions are the following:

- `unwrap()` -- if you're confident there's *no way* you could try to access an element that isn't there
- `unwrap_or()` -- if you want to handle the possible error more comprehensively

You can of course use any other techniques for handling `Option`s such as `unwrap_or_else()` or `if let`, but the above two seem most natural to me.